# Как преобразовать html код в текст?

Tags: php

На сайте есть html код, выглядит он так:

`&Bcy;&rcy;&yucy;&ncy;&iecy;&tcy;&kcy;&acy;`

но на самом деле это слово **Брюнетка**

Как преобразовать его в нормальный текст?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884550/converting-html-to-plain-text-in-php-for-e-mail - смотрите ответ к вопросу.

Comment: @Quazimorda это то что нужно! Если можете оформить это в ответ - я отмечу его галочкой. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Не вижу там нормального ответа, html_entity_decode()